# Kohana simple read from database

Tags: kohana

i am trying to retrieve some simple data from the database, and i don't know where i am wrong.

i want to get all the inactive users from my database. For that, i have in my controller:

```
    public function action_useremails()
{   
    $users = Model::factory('user')->where('user_status', '=', 2);  
    $this->view->users = $users;
}
```

and in the view:

```
 <? foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><span><?= $user; ?></span></td>

    </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

butm even though i have inactive users, i don't see anything in the view. I wonder where am i wrong?
   }

Answer (score 1):

You're building the query, but not executing it. Try:

```
$this->view->users = $users->execute();
```

also consider that the `$users` variable in the view will be an array of arrays, you'll have to echo the right element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Kohana 2, your query must be:

```
$users = Model::factory('user')->where('user_status', 2)->find();
```

Note the args in where() block & the find() at last. Without find(), you are just building the query, but not running it.

Docs: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm#find

If it is KO3, it has to be similar to the above.

Comment: Judging from the OP's `where()` method, it is Kohana 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

for v3.0 add the find_all() method at the end:

```
$users = Model::factory('user')->where('user_status', '=', 2)->find_all();
```

It executes the query you built before with the other methods.